# How to force to make HTTP requests from a frontend running on HTTPS?

Tags: javascript, http, https, axios, localhost

I have a frontend running on HTTPS locally with a local certificate. I'd like to hit a local backend that is on HTTP.

I added the meta tag to my index.html to allow for this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

...but axios refuses to do it:

```
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000',
            url: '/test',
            data: {
                firstName: 'Will',
                lastName: 'Smith'
            }
        }).then((result) => {
            console.log('done!');
        }
```

Note that I explicitly add http to the baseUrl. Still, I get this:

```
POST https://localhost:3000/test net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

Axios still sends through https.

I tried using fetch:

```
       fetch('http://localhost:3000/test', {
            method : "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                firstName: 'Finn',
                lastName: 'Williams'
            }),
        }).then((response) => {
            console.log('done! ' + response.json());
        ).catch((error) => {
            console.log('error');
        });
```

Then finally a raw XMLHttpRequest request:

```
        const http = new XMLHttpRequest();

        http.open("POST", 'http://localhost:3000/test', true);

        // Call a function when the state
        http.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                alert(http.responseText);
            }
        }
        http.send(JSON.stringify({
            firstName: 'Finn',
            lastName: 'Williams'
        }));
```

But every time the browser seems to switch to HTTPS and it fails with that same error.

Is it possible to make this happen?

Comment: Isn't it possible to use just `//localhost:3000/test` so without `http`/`https` prefix, forcing the browser to decide?

Comment: That wouldn't work because the browser would pick HTTPS. The browser is running on HTTPS. I want to make an HTTP request.

Comment: It's not possible due to Same origin policy. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). Or you can have a server side solution to redirect https requests to http.

Comment: @PankajTanwar if you make it an answer I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible due to [Same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). Or you can have a server side solution to redirect https requests to http.